# REST API Excel VBA GET call with variable input

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I am trying to perform a GET call with a where clause on an id. The back end is set up and the call works when you put the URL into a browser however it does take some time to load. However, when I try the GET call from Excel I get an HTTP Error: 500. "Reason: Illegal Character in query at position: 54"
 My variable portion of the URL is  `/?q={"user_id":"abc12345"}`
The VBA input is `/?q={""user_id"":""" & vUser & """}"`
  The 54th position is the first bracket. Does vba require some other syntax?

I also tried putting in a wait function to see if it wasn't waiting for the execution. Didn't Help.

Any idea why it works in the browser but not in the VBA? 
Below is the Object I am using:

```
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
http.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
http.Open "GET", URL, False
http.send
```

Comment: can you please show the url you are putting in the browser if possible?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the exact URL. Are there any things I could try?